# SFML sprite keeps repeating without keypress

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

This code was supposed to make my sprite-sheet change its part of the image,
and while it does that it does not quite respond to any keypress but keeps rapidly changing from one sprite to other without any keyboard input.

Here is the code that causes that kind of bug or error:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

sf::RenderWindow window;
window.create(sf::VideoMode(1000, 600), "Ludus");
sf::Texture mTexture;
sf::Sprite  mPlayer;

enum Move { Left, Right};
sf::Vector2i source(1, Left);

if (!mTexture.loadFromFile("Image.png"))
{
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
};

mPlayer.setTexture(mTexture);

while (window.isOpen()) {

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
        source.y = Right;
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
        source.y = Left;
    }

    source.x++;
    if (source.x * 97 >= 291)
        source.x = 0;

    mPlayer.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(source.x * 97, source.y * 91, 97, 91));
    window.draw(mPlayer);
    window.display();
    window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
return 0;
}
```

### Update:

Adding three `floats` with the name `frameCounter`, `switchFrame`, `frameSpeed` fixed it as follows,

```
    frameCounter += frameSpeed * clock.restart().asSeconds();
    if (frameCounter >= switchFrame) {
        frameCounter = 0;
        source.x++;
    if (source.x * 97 >= mTexture.getSize().x)
        source.x = 0;
    }
```

`frameCounter` was assigned the value of 0,`switchFrame` 100 and `frameSpeed` 650.

Comment: You keep changing `source.x` every frame.

Comment: If you mean in the 'if' statement, I'm pretty sure that it won't play any sprite without that part but just the middle ones

Comment: Let me put some emphasis on LogicStuff's comment: You keep changing `source.x` **every frame**. Additionally, think about (or measure, actually) how much time you need to process one frame.

Comment: That fixed it, It just went to fast and I could not see what was happening so i mistook it as a bug, but it did what it was supposed to do!